# jQuery to fade entire website content, to reveal background image

Tags: jquery

I've got a site with a full size background image. I'm looking to include a button or link titled "Show background photo", or something like that. Once clicked the entire page would fade out leaving the background image visible, and in the center another link/ button would fade in saying "Show Page Content". Once clicked, would fade back in the website content.

Hope this makes sense. I've found a good example: http://ines-papert.de/en/home
I know I could steal the code from that site, but that would be cheating, nor would I understand it.

I'm a novice with jQuery, and am unsure where to start with the code. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the background image? on the body element itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have the "Show Photo" button set the `z-index` CSS attribute of your image and close button so that it appears above all of the other website content. That, or set `display:none` on your main content div and have the image/button in a separate div.

```
$('#showPhotoButton').click(function()
{
    $('div#mainContent').hide();
    $('#showPhotoButton').hide();
    $('#hidePhotoButton').show();
};

$('#hidePhotoButton').click(function()
{
    $('div#mainContent').show();
    $('#showPhotoButton').show();
    $('#hidePhotoButton').hide();
}
```

Note I've left animations out from this. This is a starting point, you can look up and add whatever animations you like (either use jQuery's duration parameter on the [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method, or maybe [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)).